# <receiver> class not registering implicit intent sent from same app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I have an Android app with a homescreen widget that has buttons. When setting up the widget I use the code:

```
    Intent intentPlayPause = new Intent(context.getString(R.string.WidgetPlayPauseKey));
    PendingIntent pendingIntentPlayPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intentPlayPause, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetPlayPauseButton, pendingIntentPlayPause);
```

And I have a dedicated class to receiving widget broadcasts and doing a few other basic things. The onReceive method is never called. Here's some code from that:

```
public class WidgetBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("Sleep Timer", "Receiver Bcast in widget receiver: " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

And in the manifest for this receiver class:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".WidgetBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="@string/WidgetStopKey" />
                <action android:name="@string/WidgetPlayPauseKey" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But the onReceive method is simply never called. If I change the button to use an explicit intent instead of an implicit one, it works fine, but I would like to know why it doesn't work with an implicit intent. I'm having the same problem in another part of my app so I would really like to find out why the receiver isn't registering implicit intents. Also, I've tried changing "exported" to true on both the receiver and widget classes in the manifest but that doesn't help.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: minSdkVersion 18

targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: "If I change the button to use an explicit intent instead of an implicit one, it works fine" -- not only that but it fixes the security flaw (right now, any app can send the broadcast to your receiver) and it will work on Android 8.0+ (where the implicit broadcast will not). "I would like to know why it doesn't work with an implicit intent" -- as Vyacheslav suggests, try not using a string resource for `android:name` in the `<action>` elements.

Comment: Changing it to a string literal did fix it. Is it a security flaw since I have set exported to false on the receiver? Per the docs for the "exported" tag on a <receiver>: 
_Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — true if it can, and false if not. If false, the only messages the broadcast receiver can receive are those sent by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID._ So my receiver should only be receiving messages from my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a simple string instead of string from resources in manifest file. I mean your broadcast receiver tries to catch namely '@string/blabla' instead of your idea.

Change to 'my.custom.receiver.the.best.of.all':

`<action android:name="my.custom.receiver.the.best.of.all" />`

Comment: That was it! Out of curiosity, do you know of any way to use a resource instead of the literal string for the action name in the manifest?

Comment: In case of resources' usage this strong may vary . values and values-es ,for instance, have got different values

Comment: @Shredder2794 in order to prevent this distinguish the Google developers removed this feature